# Autocomplete search input with EasyAutocomplete plugin with multiple values

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using EasyAutocomplete plugin to auto complete search box, plugin works fine, when I search for only one type. I mean I have only one option to search, while I want that I can search with multiple values, i.e. by name, or last name etc..

here is my code:

```
var options = {
        url: "https://coincap.io/front",

        getValue: "long",

        template: {
            type: "description",
            fields: {
                description: "short"
            }
        },

        list: {
            match: {
                enabled: true
            },

        },

        theme: "plate-dark"
    };

    $("#searching").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

now this is api from where I get values of crypto currencies and currently I am searching with its `long` name and it works fine, but I want to search with also `short` name.

sorry for my bad english.. I hope you got my problem.
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This plugin allows to use functions, and through functions you can do this.

```
var options = {
    url: "https://coincap.io/front",

    getValue: function(element){
                 return element.long+" - "+element.short;
              },
   /*
    template: {
        type: "description",
        fields: {
            description: "short"
        } 
    }, */

    list: {
        match: {
            enabled: true
        },

    },

    theme: "plate-dark"
};

$("#searching").easyAutocomplete(options);
```